# Using custom dimensions with google analytics for android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get the custom dimensions feature of Google Analytics for Android (V2) working on my Android app.

I have everything else working but I can't get it reporting the custom dimension.

I have the custom dimension "age" defined on the web client.

Right now my `onStart()` looks like:

```
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
    String dimensionValue = "20-29";
    Tracker tracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();
    tracker.setCustomDimension(1, dimensionValue);
    tracker.trackView();
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check out the lastest SDK release [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources) and make sure it was not a bug in the previous version?

Also, the format of the track calls has changed from track* to send* to be consistent across APIs so you'll need to use the following format.

```
Tracker tracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();
tracker.setCustomDimension(1, "myValue");    
tracker.sendView();
```